# Use functions from other files in Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How can I write a function in a separate swift file and use it (import it) to my ViewController.swift file? I have written a lot of code and all of the code is in the ViewController.swift file, I really need to make this look good and place functions on separate files, for cleaner code. I have functions dealing with parsing HTML, functions dealing with ordering results, presenting results, responding to user actions, etc. Many thanks for any help!

```
if let htmlString = String(contentsOfURL: checkedUrl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {


                // Parsing HTML

                let opt = CInt(HTML_PARSE_NOERROR.value | HTML_PARSE_RECOVER.value)

                var err : NSError?

                var parser = HTMLParser(html: htmlString, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, option: opt, error: &err)

                var bodyNode = parser.body


                // Create an array of the part of HTML you need

                if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.findChildTags("h4") { //inputNodes is an array with all the "h4" tag strings

                    for node in inputNodes {

                        let result = html2String(node.rawContents)

                        println("Nyheter: \(result)")

                    }
                }
```

When I add that function to a separate swift file, how can I use it in my ViewDidLoad method using a "shorthand"? A short keyword that grabs that chunk of code and use it?

Comment: Just use: `swiftc main.swift functions.swift -o a.out`

Answer (score 11):

Easy. You just create a new Swift file into your Xcode project (**File - New - File - Swift file** or just **⌘-N**) and put your functions and classes there. No need to import anything in your view controller file as both files are part of the same package and thus see each others functions and types (unless marked as private).

```
func parseHtml(url: NSURL) -> String { ... your code goes here ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! But let me be more clear. See update in question, thanks again!

Comment: I don't really understand what is the problem? You define the function in the other file and just call it like you call other functions.  Can you post the full code of the file and how are you trying to call it from the view controller file.

Comment: You can use a closure and pass functions around this way

Comment: If you have a function that you want to reuse across a specific class ex. UITableViewController, you can create an extension of that class and define those functions once to be shared by all.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `singletons`.

Create NSObject in `User.swift`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {
    var name: String = 0

    func getName() -> String{
        name = "Erik Lydecker"
        return name
    }
}
```

Then initialize your object and trigger the method there.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let instanceOfUser = User()
        instanceOfUser.getName() // Erik Lydecker
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a **Utils** `class`, filled with `static variables/functions`

For example:

```
class Utils {
    static func convert(to variable: String) -> Int? {
        ... do some stuff to variable
        return newVariable
    }
}

// on your ViewController.swift

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let converted = Utils.convert(to: "123") {
        print(converted)
    }
}
```

By making use of static functions you can access them anywhere and everywhere to reuse them.

`------------------`

Another way is to make use of `extensions`

For example:

```
extension String {
    var toInt: Int? {
        return Int(self)
    }
}

// on your ViewController.swift

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let converted = "SomeValue".toInt {
        print(converted)
    }
}
```

Both of these can be used in many different scenarios.