# swift equivalent of header files in C?

Tags: c, swift

I have simple question. In my Xcode project, I have several functions that I use more than once in several viewcontrollers. To declutter the code, I want to make another file that contains these functions so that my code in viewcontrollers become less bloated with code. In C you can do this with header files, but I dont know how to do this in Swift. I searched for some basic keywords but did not find anything on google.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a *class* or a *structure,* not a header file.

Comment: I think you'll just create a class or structure and will be able to use the methods it in other files without any type of include.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use functions from other files in Swift Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780862/use-functions-from-other-files-in-swift-xcode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something you generally should do with a header file in C. This is just code reuse.

If you have pure functions, then just define the functions and put them in a file.

If you have methods that you want a view controller to have access to, you generally do that by defining a protocol and adding methods via an extension. For example:

```
protocol ExtraMethods {}

extension ExtraMethods {
    func doSomething() -> Int { return 1 }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, ExtraMethods {}
```

Alternately you can add methods to all view controllers, or you could restrict `ExtraMethods` to view controllers (`extension ExtraMethods where Self: UIViewController`). There are a number of approaches with extensions. But none are related to C header files.

Answer (score 2):

While Swift does have header files, they're not what you're looking for.

If all you want is to break up your code into reusable units, Swift is an object oriented language and you should [organize your code into classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html#ID464) as well as [protocols (which I believe everyone else calls interfaces)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html#ID466).

As for organizing your code into multiple files, use the [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/). The documentation has many simple examples like [example-package-playingcard](https://github.com/apple/example-package-playingcard).